# 2 wordpress installs on same domain with nginx & varnish, one doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, nginx, varnish

I have inherited a web project in which one domain hosts 2 wordpress installs (domain.com & domain.com/blog). I will later combine the two but for now they have to stay separate. I am moving the site to an ubuntu LEMP server and one of the wordpress installs is just showing a blank page. I am sure it has something to do with my config. Can someone help me?

```
server {

server_name www.domain.com;
listen [::]:8080 deferred;
port_in_redirect off;
server_tokens off;
autoindex off;

client_max_body_size 20m;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;

root /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs;
index index.html index.htm index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;

# Define default caching of 24h
expires 86400s;
add_header Pragma public;
add_header Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

# deliver a static 404
error_page 404 /404.html;
location  /404.html {
    internal;
}

# Deliver 404 instead of 403 "Forbidden"
error_page 403 = 404;

# Do not allow access to files giving away your WordPress version
location ~ /(\.|wp-config.php|readme.html|licence.txt) {
    return 404;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

# Don't log robots.txt requests
location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

# Rewrite for versioned CSS+JS via filemtime
location ~* ^.+\.(css|js)$ {
    rewrite ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 last;
    expires 31536000s;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}

# Aggressive caching for static files
location ~* \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|s$
    expires 31536000s;
    access_log off;
   log_not_found off;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
}

# pass PHP scripts to Fastcgi listening on Unix socket
# Do not process them if inside WP uploads directory
# If using Multisite or a custom uploads directory,
# please set the */uploads/* directory in the regex below
location ~* (^(?!(?:(?!(php|inc)).)*/uploads/).*?(php)) {
    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_config;
    include fastcgi_params;


}

# Deny access to hidden files
location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
}

    location ~ /blog/ {

    root /srv/www/domain.com/htdocs;

    try_files $uri = 404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The regexp for the "aggressive caching of static files" misses a closing bracket.